# tinymce textarea body-class doesn't apply

Tags: css, tinymce, textarea, stylesheet

I work with tinymce textareas in a jsp. I want to apply a css style only in one textarea.

Textarea definition  is

```
tinymce.init({
        selector : "textarea",
        body_class: 'text1=styleTextArea'   

    });
```

The definition of style in jsp is

```
.styleTextArea {
    color: #000;
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

I work with Firefox. In navigator console Firefox the output is:

```
<body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body styleTextArea" data-id="text1" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true">
<p> </p></body>
```

But styleTextArea style doesn't apply because font-size isn't 14.

How can I apply body-class only id textarea tinymce

Definition text1 in jsp

```
<textarea  path="text1"
                            name="text1" id="text1">

                </textarea>
```

**EDITED**

I have a css in the path /resources/css/textarea.css

I modified the jsp with

```
tinymce.init({
        selector : "textarea",
        body_class: 'text1=/resources/css/textarea.css'



    });
```

This is the browser navigator

```
<body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body /resources/css/textarea.css" data-id="text1" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true">
<p></p></body>
```

I don't understand very well how to apply the class.

Answer (score 0):

The `body_class` (and `body_id`) configuration options should not reference CSS files they are simply used to define a `class` or `id` that should be applied to the `<body>` tag in the editor:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-appearance/#body_class
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-appearance/#body_id

For example:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  body_id: 'my_id'
});
```

...or...

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  body_class: 'my_class'
});
```

Separate from this you can use the `content_css` configuration option to define CSS to apply to the `class` or `id` you add to the `<body>` tag via an external CSS file.  For example:

```
tinyMCE.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  content_css : 'myCusomStyles.css'  
});
```

The CSS file you use should have declarations that style the `class` or `id` you assigned:

```
body.my_class {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```